# How to completely remove chromium browser from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, chromium

I installed chromium using:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Then I want to completely remove it. I used:

```
sudo apt-get remove chromium --purge
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium
rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium
sudo rm -rf /etc/chromium
```

But it is still there. If I click Activities and type `Chrom..` I see `Chromium`. And when I click it it open the Chromium browser. I do not want to see it in my computer. How to remove it.

Comment: you install `chromium-browser` but uninstall `chromium`.

Comment: I do not get what are the difference between Chromium-browser, google-chrome, and chromium? Very confusing.

Comment: `chromium-browser` is just the package name for `chromium` in Ubuntu, probably because `chromium` itself was taken ?! Google Chrome is a browser from Chrome that is built on chromium project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

did you try to do this?

```
sudo apt purge --remove chromium-browser -y
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean -y
```

Please be aware that it will delete all user saved bookmarks, history etc once you enter these commands.

Assuming you are using Ubuntu, click on the dash button in the launcher and search for 'System info'. Then, open 'System info' and move to 'Default applications' section. Then, click on the dropdown list next to Web. There, select 'Google Chrome' and it will be selected as the default web browser for your system.

[image]

**Using GUI** -
If you want to delete the settings from gnome [GUI], you must delete the config folder for that user (placed in its home, as a hidden folder, thus the . at the start of the name).

You may delete that folder using the terminal or you may open the home folder in Nautilus and press Ctrl+H to show the hidden files and folders, then delete the folder you want to delete as you would do with any other file.

Comment: also delete/remove `sudo rm -rf ~/.config/chromium`

Comment: No problem. I installed it by mistake. I want to remove it. Will it delete its configurations too? Because  I want to install Google Chrome and want the Coogle Chrome's default configurations.

Comment: yes, it will delete everything - which means your Chromium browser's configurations, extensions, plugins etc. But your question states you want to completely remove it!
It wont interfere with the `google-chrome stable` browser though. worry not.

Comment: I want to remove Chromium (which has blue logo). I want to install Google Chrome (colored logo: Red, Green, Yellow). Of course not because of colors. But what I need for my experiment in Google Chrome.

Comment: And I care about Google Chrome default configurations. So i do not want to retain any other thing (Chromium-browser) configurations.

Comment: it will remove only chromium browsers dependencies, it wont delete anything from google-chrome-stable browser.

Answer (score 3):

I could not remove chromium with apt and it took me a while to figure out that it was installed with snap.
To remove it run this in a console:

```
sudo snap remove chromium
```